Extracting text from a pdf file with differents strcuture failed how to properly do it Not all texts is extracted , just a portion is extracted
I am trying to extract text from CV in pdf extension. I come up with this script but I have a problem. The script does not extract all the text and I have problem to identify different block of the document. Here is the script below following by the result and the pdf file as an example.

import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import json
import os
import re
import shutil
import glob

def extract_blocks_from_pdf(file_path):
    document = fitz.open(file_path)
    blocks = []

    for page_num in range(len(document)):
        page = document.load_page(page_num)
        blocks += page.get_text("blocks")  # Récupérer les blocs de texte


    return blocks

def classify_blocks(blocks):
    sections = {
        "Résumé de carrière": [],
        "Compétences": [],
        "Rôle": [],
        "Formations": [],
        "Expériences Professionnelles": [],
        "Autres Compétences": []
    }

    current_section = None

    for block in blocks:
        print(type(block))
        text = block[-3].strip()
        if re.search(r'Résumé de carrière', text, re.IGNORECASE):
            current_section = "Résumé de carrière"
        elif re.search(r'Rôle', text, re.IGNORECASE):
            current_section = "Rôle"
        elif re.search(r'Compétences', text, re.IGNORECASE):
            current_section = "Compétences"
        elif re.search(r'Formations', text, re.IGNORECASE):
            current_section = "Formations"
        elif re.search(r'Expériences Professionnelles', text, re.IGNORECASE):
            current_section = "Expériences Professionnelles"
        elif re.search(r'Autres Compétences', text, re.IGNORECASE):
            current_section = "Autres Compétences"
        elif current_section and text:
            sections[current_section].append(text)

    return sections

def process_pdfs_to_json(pdf_files, output_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    else: 
        items = os.listdir(output_dir)
        if items:
            shutil.rmtree(output_dir)
            os.makedirs(output_dir)

    for pdf_file in pdf_files:
        blocks = extract_blocks_from_pdf(pdf_file)
        structured_blocks = classify_blocks(blocks)
        
        file_name = os.path.basename(pdf_file).replace('.pdf', '.json')
        json_path = os.path.join(output_dir, file_name)
        
        with open(json_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            json.dump(structured_blocks, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)



def read_json(json_path):
    with open(json_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    return data   

# Example of usage:
pdf_dir = "test"  
pdf_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(pdf_dir, "*.pdf")) 


output_dir = "structured_cv_jsons"
process_pdfs_to_json(pdf_files, output_dir)


the variable pdf_files contains different pdf files.
Here are the result of a single file

{
    "Résumé de carrière": [
        "Technicien de support applicatif/fonctionnel N2+, Technicien de support \napplicatif/fonctionnel N2+, Coach CV"
    ],
    "Compétences": [],
    "Rôle": [
        "• \nTraitement des tickets et des incidents",
        "• \nAide à la diminution du volume de tickets entrants et des temps de traitement des incidents",
        "• \nConception et construction de solutions agiles répondant à des cas d'usages fournis par la \n Power Platform Academy",
        "• \nÉvaluation et amélioration continue des modules Microsoft Power Platform",
        "• \nTraitement des tickets et des incidents",
        "• \nIndustrialisation et automatisation des audits parties fixe et mobile",
        "ISEP | ISEP \njanvier 2018 – juin 2018 (6 mois) \nProjet : Cybersécurité \nFormation Architecture Cybersécurité et intégration de composants de sécurité \nMission : \nPanorama : \nRGPD, Ecosystème du crime, Logique de l'attaquant, Sureté - Sécurité - Données, Ecosystème de la sécurité, Normes ISO \n27001, 27005, Production - Exploitation & ROI, Bonnes pratiques & historique, \nRetours d'expérience \nArchitecture : \nLes architectures, Architectures réseaux, Architectures applicative \nIntégration : \nInfrastructures Sécurisées, Serveurs, Terminaux, Techniques pour l'intégration \nProjet : \nArchitecture, Intégration, Management",
        "3/3 | Curriculum Vitae",
        "IEP | IEP \njanvier 2018 – juin 2018 (6 mois) \nProjet : Cybersécurité \nFormation Architecture Cybersécurité et intégration de composants de sécurité \nMission : \nPanorama : \nRGPD, Ecosystème du crime, Logique de l'attaquant, Sureté - Sécurité - Données, Ecosystème de la sécurité, Normes ISO \n27001, 27005, Production - Exploitation & ROI, Bonnes pratiques & historiqu"
    ],
    "Formations": [
        "• \nCertification Tricentis TOSCA : \nAutomatisation des tests",
        "• \nISEP - 2 BADGES - Architecture \nCybersécurité et Intégration de \ncomposants de sécurité (labellisée \nSecNumedu et reconnue CNCP)",
        "2/3 | Curriculum Vitae"
    ],
    "Expériences Professionnelles": [],
    "Autres Compétences": []
}


As you can see the not all sections are included even all the texts. Could you help me figure it out how to properly done it.
here is a link of the pdf folder containing one test example of the pdf used. 
I try to extract text block by block but not all the texte are extracted.

I change to the one you proposed , thank you, you can acess it freely now.
